# Split and Match rows in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008

My table looks like this:

```
ID      Column
----------------------------------
1       This is a Sample Text
2       Sample Text is typed here
3       Here the sample text is
4       Typing a sample
```

and I need the output to be like this:

```
ID Column                     MostCommon  Common1  Common2  NonCommon
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  This is a Sample Text      Sample      Text     is       This a
2  Sample Text is typed here  Sample      Text     is       typed here
3  Here the sample text is    Sample      Text     is       Here the
4  Typing a sample            sample      NULL     NULL     Typing A
```

Can anybody help me to write a sp/function/query in SQL Server 2008

'sample' appears in all rows. so i can keep it as most common word, 'text,'is', the next most common and can be found in row# 1,2,3. All other words are not matching with other rows and will be moved to Non common category

Comment: Can you please **explain in English** what you're trying to achieve?? Just giving us input and output and letting us **guess** what you're trying to do isn't very helpful.....

Comment: Why is `Text` preferred over `is` as `Common1`? (is it based on length?). What is the rule for defining something as common? (Exists in 75% of rows? All but 1?). Can there be any row counts <>4?

Comment: Find the common pattern between rows.

Comment: 'sample' appears in all rows. so i can keep it as most common word, 'text,'is', the next most common and can be found in row# 1,2,3. All other words are not matching with other rows and will be moved to Non common category!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do it, first you have to create a function that splits strings, afterwards count the occurrences and display them as you want. It makes it more complicated because you want to display variable number of columns:

```
/*
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_XML
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' + 
                   REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
GO
*/

CREATE TABLE #t(ID INT, Col VARCHAR(1000))
INSERT #t
VALUES
(1,       'This is a Sample Text'),
(2,       'Sample Text is typed here'),
(3,       'Here the sample text is'),
(4,       'Typing a sample')

DECLARE @MinimumNumberOfOccurances INT = 2

SELECT  a.ID,
        a.Col,
        b.Item
INTO    #SplitedStrings
FROM    #t a
CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings_XML(a.Col, N' ') b


SELECT  b.Item,
        COUNT(*) cnt
INTO    #SplitedStringsGrouped
FROM    #t a
CROSS   APPLY dbo.SplitStrings_XML(a.Col, N' ') b
GROUP   BY b.Item

SELECT      b.*,
            a.cnt
INTO        #ResultTable
FROM        #SplitedStringsGrouped a
RIGHT JOIN  #SplitedStrings b ON 
            b.Item = a.Item
            AND a.cnt > @MinimumNumberOfOccurances
ORDER BY    b.ID, a.cnt DESC, LEN(a.Item) DESC

DECLARE @ColumnNames VARCHAR(1000) = STUFF(
(
    SELECT  ',[' + Item + ']'
    FROM    #SplitedStringsGrouped
    WHERE   cnt > @MinimumNumberOfOccurances
    FOR     XML PATH('')
)
, 1, 1, '')

DECLARE @TableHeader VARCHAR(1000) = STUFF(
(
    SELECT  ',MAX([' + Item + ']) AS [Common' + 
            CAST((ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                (ORDER BY cnt DESC, LEN(Item) DESC) - 1) 
                    AS VARCHAR(5)) 
            + ']'
    FROM    #SplitedStringsGrouped
    WHERE   cnt > @MinimumNumberOfOccurances
    FOR     XML PATH('')
)
, 1, 1, '')

SELECT  ID,
        Item,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
            (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) Num
INTO    #NonCommon
FROM    #ResultTable
WHERE   cnt IS NULL

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(1000) = 
'
SELECT  MAX(pvt.ID) ID, MAX(pvt.Col) [Column],
        '+@TableHeader+',
        RTRIM((
            SELECT  a.Item + '' ''
            FROM    #NonCommon a
            WHERE   a.ID = pvt.ID
            FOR     XML PATH('''')
        )) NonCommon        
FROM    #ResultTable a
PIVOT   (
    MAX(Item) FOR Item IN ('+@ColumnNames+')
) pvt
GROUP  BY pvt.ID
'

EXEC(@sql)

DROP TABLE #t
DROP TABLE #SplitedStringsGrouped
DROP TABLE #SplitedStrings
DROP TABLE #ResultTable
DROP TABLE #NonCommon
```

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it works. I hoped there would be a simpler solution but this one is the only I could think of. You can set different value to `@MinimumNumberOfOccurances` to define how many times a word has to be found in order to be considered common.